# Center fixed menu with unknown width

Tags: javascript, css

I need to have a menu centered and fixed in the top of the page. The content of the menu is dynamic, so its width is not known in advance. The solutions that I found on the web suppose that either the width is known, or the position is not fixed.

Is there a way to do this?

CSS and JavaScript solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). Answers most centering questions, with diagrams and demos.

In your case the easiest way is probably just to use two elements. Use `position: fixed` and `text-align: center` on the outermost div. Then set the centered element to `display: inline`. (You have to be careful about character spaces when you do this.)

See here:

http://codepen.io/pen/7169/1

Comment: If it's for a menu, display:inline-block; would porperbly be a better choise. like http://jsfiddle.net/TA8uy/1/

Answer (score -1):

Just create a wrapper div, and set that to fixed and set the align to center. That should give you what you're looking for.

```
​<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;" align="center">
    <ul>
        <li>Menuitem</li>
        <li>Menuitem2</li>
    </ul>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I think you mean `text-align`. `align` is not a css property.

Comment: You can align a div's content using the <div align="center">. It's not CSS, but it's a markup tool.

Comment: Well, align is deprecated because it introduces weird document flow problems. Thus it isn't future proof. You really shouldn't be using it if you care about your layouts working in the future.